Почему не отображается кирилица в VS Code на mac OS?
Выбрал в VS Code - clang ++ как компилятор, но когда пытаюсь вывести в терминал что-то на кирилице, он выдает ошибку. Я новичок и поэтому не уверен, но помоему это должно зависить от компилятора, и в этом странность, ведь когда я просто вызываю выполнение идентичного кода через встроенный маковский терминал, не используя VS Code всё работает:
#include <iostream>
#include <locale.h>
#include <cstdlib>



int main() {
    printf("Привет");
}

Вот так выглядит это в VS Code:

Вот что получается напрямую:

Я пытался подключить кирилицу через:
#include <locale.h>


int main() {
    setlocale(0,"Russian");

}

И самое интересное, что вроде как это работало, но недавно я снова вошел в программу и она сново перестала выводить кирилицу, хотя я ничего не менял.

VSCode в правом-нижнем углу показывает кодировку файла, какая у вас?

Кодировка Windows 1251

Поставьте UTF-8 (клик туда и "save with encoding"). setlocale не нужен.

Спасибо большое! Помогло
